# How to Adapt Array of Enums Conversion with Updated @TypeDef Annotation in Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm working on migrating an existing Hibernate entity to use the latest version of Hibernate, and I've encountered an issue with converting an array of enums due to recent changes in the @TypeDef annotation. Previously, I used the following configuration to map an array of enums to a PostgreSQL enum type:

```java
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(
        name = "host-enum-array",
        typeClass = EnumArrayType.class,
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = EnumArrayType.SQL_ARRAY_TYPE, value = "HOST_SERVICES")
        }
    )
})
@Entity
public class Host {
    @Type(type = "host-enum-array")
    @Column(name = "hostServices", columnDefinition = "HOST_SERVICES[]")
    @ColumnTransformer(
        forColumn = "host_services",
        read = "cast(hostServices as text[])",
        write = "?::HOST_SERVICES[]"
    )
    private HostServices[] hostServices;
}
```

However, this approach no longer seems to work as expected. I've already reviewed a related issue on GitHub (https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/issues/514), but I'm not sure if my implementation is incorrect or if there's a new way to achieve this with the updated @TypeDef usage.

**Additional Context:**

```
Hibernate version old: 5.6.12
Hibernate version new: 6.4.0
Database: PostgreSQL
```

PostgresSQL Column I try to map to is defined as:

```sql
CREATE TYPE HOST_SERVICES AS ENUM('CALENDARSERVICE', 'COMPOUNDMANAGEMENT');
ALTER TABLE host ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS host_services HOST_SERVICES[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, actual results, and expected results. All as [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) or even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), but - **no images**.

Comment: In addition to @Belayer comment, also provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't know the packages and dependencies that your code uses.